# Loading compiled bootstrap into rails withot any gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

What is the cleanest way to import twitter-bootstrap into rails without any gem?
So far I've been manually copying the css/js files into `vendor/assets/javascripts`, `vendor/assets/stylesheets`

Is there a way to do this without moving the files into separate folders?

Comment: If you would like to use downloaded version , not the gem , this is the only way . Consider to change image paths in your css with asset path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied bootstrap into `lib/bootstrap`

I'm using `make bootstrap` to compile it, then running a rake task to copy the compiled files into `vendor/assets`

```
require 'fileutils'

task :bootme do
  compiled_bootstrap = 'lib/bootstrap/bootstrap'
  FileUtils.cp_r(compiled_bootstrap + '/css/.', 'vendor/assets/stylesheets/')
  FileUtils.cp_r(compiled_bootstrap + '/img/.', 'vendor/assets/images/')
  FileUtils.cp_r(compiled_bootstrap + '/js/.', 'vendor/assets/javascripts/')
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could all CSS and JS in `vendor/assets/twitter-bootstrap`.

Then in `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`:

```
//=require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/twitter-bootstrap
```

And in your `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css`:

```
*= require ../../../vendor/assets/twitter-bootstrap
```

For non JS or CSS assets like images to go in non-standard directory, in either `config/application.rb` or environment-specific config, you'd use:

```
# can add more than one path string or regexp(s)
config.assets.precompile += ['../../../vendor/assets/twitter-bootstrap/*.png']
```

The recommended way is to either use a well-maintained gem for your assets, or continue to put vendor JS and CSS assets in `vendor/assets/javascripts` and `vendor/assets/stylesheets`, respectively.

Comment: A bit ugly, but it might work. Although I'll probably end up creating a rake task to compile the files and copy them in `vendor/assets`

Comment: Yeah, it looks ugly because it isn't the standard way of doing things. If you are going to be tweaking bootstrap, etc. a lot, then having the code in vendor is a good idea. If you won't be touching it or looking at it outside of the browser that much, then reconsider having it in a gem. You can even make your own gem for it if you want full control, and there are plenty of examples out there about how to do it, e.g. http://prioritized.net/blog/gemify-assets-for-rails/

Comment: If you read that external blog link, note that you don't have to push it to Rubygems either- you could have bundle point at local source for the gem, or have it point at GitHub or another repo. Good luck.

Comment: Also, Josh Peek uses bower here as another way to get JS into vendor: https://gist.github.com/josh/3667224 They added bower component.json require support in Sprockets v2.6.0.